# Provider needed to be specify on a connectionstring?

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I have a very funny problem on my application, I get an error as follow:
System.ArgumentException: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

However, when I tried to speicify the provider on my connection as Provider=SQLOLEDB.1 or Provider=SQLOLEDB, then I get another error saying invalid keyword 'Provider'.

But one thing I noticed, the computer that I am targeting to had 2 different database system, will that cause this error?

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Please provide a full example of the connection string you were using when you specified the provider.

Comment: My connection string is as follow:
Data Source=MyServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;User Id=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;, just without the Provider, the connectionstring that I got from www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: can you edit with more code from your example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using ADO.NET, if you want to use distinct database systems, then you need to correct the DbConnection too, not only the connection string.

Note that you can't use an `SqlConnection` for OLEDB, you need to use `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection` instead.

Comment: I was using SqlConnection for that, so I am using the correct DbConnection as I am not using a general connection for my application.

Comment: You can't use SqlConnection for OLEDB, check my last edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing some bits of the connection string - try these

General Connection String:

```
strConnect = _T("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MyServerName;"
        "Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;"
        "User Id=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;");
```

Named Instance Connection String:

```
strConnect = _T("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MyServerName\MyInstanceName;"
    "Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;User Id=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;");
```

Trusted Security:

```
strConnect = _T("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MyServerName;"
        "Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;"
        "Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

From here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/connectionstrings.aspx#OLE DB SqlServer

Comment: But when I add Provider on my connectionstring, I got another error saying invalid keyword provider.